# In a strongly typed view, how can you show a property of a seperate but related model?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

If I have two entities like the following:

[image]

...in a strongly typed Details view of BasicEntity, is there a way to show the related ListItem's Description using the navigation properties?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple, through the navigation property you already have:

```
@(Model.ListItem.Description)
```

Comment: I tried that, but I get an "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" error.  In my Details controller method, I get BasicEntity by Id to return to the view, is there something I need to do there to also get the ListItem so the navigation property will work?